# how to shorten text length for automatically posting

Tags: javascript, html, css, maxlength

I would like to shorten the text in my article because I'm using IFTTT to post stuff automatically...
I tried this one

```
function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
    var element = document.querySelector(selector),
        truncated = element.innerText;

    if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
        truncated = truncated.substr(0,maxLength) + '...';
    }
    return truncated;
}

document.querySelector('p').innerText = truncateText('p', 30);
```

but it doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could do:

```
    function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {

        $(selector).each(function(){
            $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,maxLength) + '...');
        });

    }


    truncateText("p",30);
```

Or in pure javascript:

```
        function truncateText(selector, maxLength) { 
         var elemts = document.getElementsByTagName(selector); 
         for(var i = 0; i < elemts .length; i++) {
              elemts[i].innerHTML =  elemts[i].innerHTML.substr(0,maxLength) + '...'; 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on jsfiddle and it is working. 
The possible solution might be to use your code after the page has loaded.

**First solution**

Move the `script` tag to the very end, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

**Second solution**

Wait the page and then use your code

```
function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
    var element = document.querySelector(selector),
    truncated = element.innerText;

    if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
       truncated = truncated.substr(0,maxLength) + '...';
    }
       return truncated;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { // After the page is loaded
       document.querySelector('p').innerText = truncateText('p', 30);
});
```